# Crontab -e messing up paths in jar-file

Tags: java, ubuntu, cron

I am running a jar-file through crontab -e with paths such as "../folder/dbfile.db".

If I run that jar-file through the terminal in Ubuntu, it works.

However, if I run it in crontab -e, the paths start from /home/myUser/ or something like that.

How would I go about solving it?

Here is my crontab -e

```
@reboot sleep 60 && java -jar Desktop/IP/server.jar > Desktop/IP/logs/server.log 2>&1
@reboot sleep 120 && java -jar Desktop/IP/backup.jar > Desktop/IP/logs/backup.log 2>&1
```

Comment: crontab starts at root, so indeed you need a `cd <right-folder>` in the crontab command, something like `@reboot sleep 60 && cd expectedFolder && java -jar...`

Comment: That works! Amazing. If you post as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Posted as an answer :)

Comment: In Java you are not guaranteed anything about the current directory.   Either use resources (which can be done in the manifest for files outside the jar) or have your code locate itself and resolve relative paths from that.

Answer (score 0):

`crontab` always starts at root, so you need a `cd <right-folder>` in the crontab command, something like:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && cd expectedFolder && java -jar ...
```